# Enable/Remove popup on mousedown/mouseup?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'd like to do as the title suggests and can get the popup to appear on mousedown with the following code, but mouseup doesn't close the popup:

```
// Quick look at info on mouse hold
marker.on("mousedown", function(e){
    this.openPopup();
});
// TODO: can we get mouseup working?
$(marker).mouseup( function(e){
    this.closePopup();
});
```

Am I missing something?  If I log within the functions I see the mousedown hitting but mouseup never happens.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that an [interactive layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#interactive-layer-mousedown) does not listen to the "mouseup" event, so the mouseup event is never called for a layer.

I think this goal can be achieved by :

- Listen to the "mouseup" event on the map
- Check whether a popup is open
- Close the popup with the `map.closePopup()` method ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816173/close-all-popups-with-leaflet-js))